# How do i make my JSON output in text-editor go to next line before the start of a new bracket using Python?

Tags: python, json, text-editor

How do I take the json output in the text-editor and organize it so that the start of a new bracket starts at the next line so it could look neat?

```
with open(output, 'w') as json_file:
      rows = list(out)
      json.dump(rows, json_file)
```

This is the end of the code which prints me out the json, but not neat.

```
[{column1:value1,column2:value1},{column1:value2,column2:value2},{column1:value3,column2:value3},{column1:value4,column2:value4}]
```

I've tried this. However i get an error message.

```
with open(output, 'w') as json_file:
       rows = list(out)
       json.dump(rows, json_file) + ',' + '\n'
```

I would like my result to look like

```
[{column1:value1,column2:value1},
{column1:value2,column2:value2}, 
{column1:value3,column2:value3},
{column1:value4,column2:value4}]
```

Comment: The thing you're looking for is called "pretty printing". If you just want to look at it, pipe your output through `jq`, otherwise do some websearch with that name, you should get a few results.

Answer (score 0):

While [json module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html) allows to choose indentation, I couldn't figure out how to produce custom layouts.
So my best solution is the following:

```
import json

path = "/path/to/json"
d = [
    {"column1": "value1", "column2": "value1"},
    {"column1": "value2", "column2": "value2"}, 
    {"column1": "value3", "column2": "value3"},
    {"column1": "value4", "column2": "value4"}
]


lines = "["
for x in d[:-1]:
    lines += json.dumps(x) + ",\n"
lines += json.dumps(d[-1]) + "]"
with open(path, "w") as f:
    f.write(lines)
```